# I am sorting gridview data using list getting "data source does not support server-side data paging" error.@jordanArron

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridPayCondition" Width="750px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="GridPayCondition_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridPayCondition_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridPayCondition_Sorting" >
```

code of aspx file:

code of cs file:

```
 protected void GridPayCondition_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
       {

           List<PayCondition> paycondition = new List<PayCondition>();
           EditPayConditionLogic epcLogic = new EditPayConditionLogic();
           paycondition = epcLogic.GetPayCondition();

           if(paycondition!=null)
           {
               var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PayCondition), e.SortExpression);
               var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<PayCondition, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, e.SortExpression), typeof(object)), param);

               if(ViewState["SortDirection"]=="DESC")
               {
                   ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
                   GridPayCondition.DataSource = paycondition.AsQueryable<PayCondition>().OrderBy(sortExpression);

               }
               else
               {
                   ViewState["SortDirection"] = "DESC";
                   GridPayCondition.DataSource = paycondition.AsQueryable<PayCondition>().OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
               }
               GridPayCondition.DataBind();
           }

       }
```

Comment: #jordanArron please help I was refering to your post.I am begginer so not able to understand this exception

Comment: SO doesn't generally operate by asking specific people for help; instead, link to any questions you need for context, or preferably just explain what you need so anyone with enough expertise can answer.

Comment: I am completely new to stackoverflow so thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error:**

> Data source does not support server-side data paging

**Cause:**

```
GridPayCondition.DataSource = paycondition.AsQueryable<PayCondition>().OrderBy(sortExpression);
```

**Solution:**

```
GridPayCondition.DataSource = paycondition.AsQueryable<PayCondition>().OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList();
```

**Reason:**

> You can’t use an IQueryable object to data bind to a GridView and
>   still use Paging and Sorting. You must return a List to the GridView
>   using the ToList() method.

Comment: thanks @suprabhat error is solved but in this code sorting is done only for the first time not for the next time. could you please help me once again?

Comment: No, not getting error as such but not able to do what I want. I want to sort the data once I clicked the header of gridview but for the second time when clicked the header sorting is not done. what should be the reason?

Comment: Are you able to call `GridPayCondition_Sorting` event. Try adding a `breakpoint` in this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridPayCondition_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
   {
       List<PayCondition> paycondition = new List<PayCondition>();
       EditPayConditionLogic epcLogic = new EditPayConditionLogic();
       paycondition1 = epcLogic.GetPayCondition();
       if (paycondition1 != null)
       {
           var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PayCondition),e.SortExpression);
           var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<PayCondition, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, e.SortExpression), typeof(object)), param);

           if ((string)ViewState["SortDirection"] == "DESC")
           {
               ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
               GridPayCondition.DataSource = paycondition1.AsQueryable<PayCondition>().OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList();
           }
           else
           {
               ViewState["SortDirection"] = "DESC";
               GridPayCondition.DataSource = paycondition1.AsQueryable<PayCondition>().OrderByDescending(sortExpression).ToList();
           }
           GridPayCondition.DataBind();
       }
```

Comment: if((string )ViewState["SortDirection"]=="DESC")

Comment: there i forgot to do typecasting so (string) is important.